# Evaluating the integral $\int_1^{\infty} \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y+1)}{x y \Gamma(x+y+2)} \ dx \ dy$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

During the study of some integrals I came across a very interesting integral, that is 
$$\int_1^{\infty} \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\Gamma(x+1)\Gamma(y+1)}{x y \Gamma(x+y+2)} \ dx \ dy$$

that is obtained by manipulating 
$$\int_0^1 \operatorname{li}(x) \operatorname{li}(1-x) \ dx$$
 Apparently nothing seems to work, but I bet you can do much more than me. So, what
tools would you recommend me to try?

Comment: Perhaps rewriting the expression in $\Gamma$ using the beta function, and replacing it with its integral form ? Or is that where you are coming from ?

Comment: @Lucian Yes, I went that way.

Answer (score 6):

To compute
$$\int_{0}^{1}\operatorname{li}(x)\operatorname{li}(1-x)\,dx$$
i'd rather exploit the fact that the logarithmic integral function admits a representation in terms of the [shifted Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials), since:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{1}\operatorname{li}(x)\,L_n(2x-1)\,dx &=& \frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}\operatorname{li}(x)\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-x)^n\,dx\\&=&\frac{1}{n!}\left.\frac{L_{n+1}(2x-1)-L_{n-1}(2x-1)}{4n+2}\operatorname{li}(x)\right|_{0}^{1}\\&-&\frac{1}{(4n+2)n!}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{L_{n+1}(2x-1)-L_{n-1}(2x-1)}{\log x}\,dx.\end{eqnarray*}$$
So, if we set $L_n(2x-1)=Q_n(x)$ for shortness, we have:
$$\operatorname{li}(x) = -\log 2-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} c_n Q_n(x), $$
where:
$$ c_n = \frac{1}{2n!}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{Q_{n+1}(x)-Q_{n-1}(x)}{\log x}\,dx \tag{1}$$
is a linear combination of logarithms of integers by Frullani's theorem and:
$$\operatorname{li}(1-x) = -\log 2-\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n c_n Q_n(x), $$
giving:
$$\int_{0}^{1}\operatorname{li}(x)\operatorname{li}(1-x)\,dx=\log^2 2+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n c_n^2}{2n+1}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: Is working in _shifted_ Legendre polynomials the clearest approach? Using the standard polynomials would seem just a matter of taking $t=2x-1$. Also, some citation of Frullani's theorem would be helpful.

Comment: @Semiclassical: since the integration range is $[0,1]$, yes, the shifted Legendre polynomials are the natural choice. The istance of Frullani's theorem I use here is just: $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-at}-e^{-bt}}{t}\,dt=\log\frac{b}{a}.$$

Comment: In $x$, yes, but for $t=2x-1$ the range is $[-1,1]$. So one could just as well use regular Legendre polynomials instead. (Though it's really just an aesthetic choice).